# Where does Windows store my imported photos from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, windows, photos, data-synchronization

I have just synced ~7700 photos/videos from my iPhone to my Windows 8.1 laptop, but I wish to view these files, except I cannot seem to find these files in a viewable format, so I can sort through them.

Comment: How exactly did you sync the photos from your iPhone? iTunes syncs photos *to* your iPhone, not *from*?

Comment: @grgarside i mean import, ill edit the question now. I opend "my computer", then selected "iphone device" or something similar, then clicked "import photos / videos", and its in the process of doing that

Comment: Okay, so that's using [Windows photo import functionality](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/17450/windows-8-import-photos), not related to iTunes?

Comment: @grgarside ah yes you are right, where would be the right place to ask this question? it doesn't appear to be suited here

Comment: Not a problem, just making sure I understand the problem fully. I will edit your question to remove the reference to iTunes.

Comment: @grgarside thanks for editing it, i've just managed to find the pictures, should i close the question or leave it as an answer?

Comment: I provided an answer already! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default location for Windows photo imports is the Pictures folder in your user account, but can be changed (and you can see where it is set) in the import settings by choosing ‘More options’ at the bottom-left of the import window.

- [How to change photo import settings in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/q/468099/156757)

> [image]
>
> [image]